# In R Residual sum of three variables

Tags: r

I want to find the residual sum of three variables I have the following code:

```
ans = 0
for (i in 1:dim(x)[1] ){
  for (j in 1:dim(x)[2]){
    ans = ans + (x[i,j] - alpha[i] - beta[j])^2
  }
}
```

where x is a matrix with dimension n,m and alpha and beta are vectors with length n,m respectively.

Whats the fastest way of doing it?

Comment: I feel like you were just about to say something, and then you stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sum((t(x - alpha) - beta) ^ 2)
```

Comment: I stand corrected this does work. I forgot to initialize my variable to zero and got the wrong output. Thanks.